# Avada has no option to change submenu hover text color in avada Theme editor. How to change this hover text color for my submenu?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, header, submenu

I want to change avada submenu text color on hover like i mention in below image. I try hard to find default option inside theme editor but i didn't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Submenu hover options are already available in the Menu Element settings so if you're using the header layout, you can select the hover state by clicking the circle that appears in front of **Submenu Text Color** field, screenshot below. Then define color for it and save changes. More details can be checked in [this article](https://www.webzando.com/blog/how-to-add-hover-effect-in-main-menu-of-avada-theme/)

[Avada submenu hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J023c.png)

Comment: This is the solution, I downvoted the other.

Answer (score 0):

By default avada doesn't provide to change hover text color of submenu but you can do using custom css option. For that you have to just visit in avada theme editor and click on Custom css.

Copy below code and paste in custom CSS editor and click on save button.

```
.fusion-main-menu .sub-menu li a:hover{
    font-family: "Fira Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border-bottom-color: #e2e2e2;
    background-color: #6f4e37;
    color: #ff9502;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

[image]